# how to check verify security of google drive folders

Tags: security, gmail, google-drive

I today uploaded some songs from my USB to my google drive.
That folder I created today morning and while the songs were being uploaded I got
an email which mentioned

> foldername - Request for access
>   someone @ gmail.com is requesting access to the following folder:

I would like to check my google drive folders security because the name of folder is very common which I created but obviously it was not shared with any one.
Fearing any breach I changed password of my gmail account. But I want to know how many of my folders are such that which might be publicly accessible I need to check I have lot of folders and files.

Comment: Due to the way Google Drive generates links to folders within your cloud storage it’s unliked somebody randomly came across your folder.  I honestly forget if you have previously shared a folder within the root directory if someone with that access can request access to additional folders.  I would contact Google directly.  Questions about Google Drive are outside the scope of Super User

Comment: Changing your password won’t revoke access to shared folders by the way. Seriously, Contact Google.